# Adobe font cache clearing is not working

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, windows

OS: Win7 x64

software: Adobe InDesign CC 2015

I modified one installed font slightly such that one character only changed. Then I uninstalled the original font, installed the modified version, cleared Windows font cache, removed every single Adobe*.lst file (which supposedly clears Adobe font cache), and then rebooted. The new font works correctly in all other Windows apps, but InDesign "remembers" the old version of this font... and only sometimes at that. If I look at a long section of text, the changed character appears both the "old" way and the "new" way at random throughout the same section. This happens in all Adobe apps.

I have found dozens of articles referencing the Adobe*.lst files as controlling the cache, but this is simply not working for me. Is there another cache somewhere that I am unaware of?

Comment: Just a thought, are you sure there are no ligatures or alternate glyphs for that character? That would explain the occurrence of both your edited version and the original

Comment: @CAI I actually did think about that after some stuff I recently read. I really don't know what I'm doing with this font editing stuff. I simply opened the file in FontForge and played around with the outline of this one character until I got it looking the way I want. How can I check for alternate representations in the data? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that is definitely the case. I found where the ligatures are defined in FontForge. Post it as an answer and I'll check it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably either alternate glyphs for the character or ligatures that include that character in the font.

You can check if this is the case in InDesign by opening the Glyphs panel (**Window → Type & Tables → Glyphs**) and searching for any other glyphs that include that character. You can open the font in any font manager or editor and check the glyphs too.